# Should I use a custom DTO Response class as an abstraction? Or is there a way to wrap/decorate ResponseEntity?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

new to using Spring Boot. Should I use a custom DTO Response class as an abstraction? Or is there a way to wrap/decorate ResponseEntity in case I need to dynamically add a new property to all the controller responses in the future?

That is, I had began creating a base response class I can use to ensure all my Spring controller methods return data in the same format? I know this is what ResponseEntity is used for, but I wanted to be able to add properties to all controller methods in the future if needed and wasn't sure how to do this with ResponseEntity?

Know it has a builder pattern, is there anyway I can pass a custom class to the ResponseEntity that I can then use as a single point to add any headers or objects in the future?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I'm also interested in how do it others. I don't think my solution is the best one, but this is best solution which I know.

```
public ResponseDto<MyClass> someMethod(HttpServletRequest req){
    MyClass someData = getDataFromSomeWhere();
    return ResponseDto.ok(someData); 
    // in error case return ResponseDto.error(errorMessage)
}
```

```
public class ResponseDto<T> {
    private boolean success;
    private String reason;  // reason uses for error case
    private T data;
    
    public static <T> ResponseDto<T> ok(T data) {
        ResponseDto<T> responseDto = new ResponseDto<>();
        responseDto.setData(data);
        responseDto.setSuccess(true);

        return responseDto;
    }

    public static ResponseDto error(String error) {
        ResponseDto responseDto = new ResponseDto<>();
        responseDto.setSuccess(false);
        responseDto.setReason(error);

        return responseDto;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was heading down that path initially (well, also with an implementation of ResponseEntity which may have not been the right path in how I handled it) but had someone pushing me to ResponseEntity but wondered how I could achieve the goal of being able to modify all responses at once down the road in the best path possible. Curious to see if others have various implementations. Going to leave this question open for a while and come back to if after I finish my next item (but will watch for replies). Thank you again!